# Why does painting with Swing behave differently in Java 8 and Java 6?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, java-8, java-6

I am working on a Java application using Swing as a GUI. In this project, I was using Java 8 Update 25. I had been writing another graphical application in Java, but I was using Java 6. In both projects, I have written the same paint() method. (Shown below) I was also calling 'repaint()' the same way too. In both projects, I am drawing a string. This string displays the value of a local int, count; Count increases by one each time the paint() method is called.

My question comes when the two projects behave differently. In Java 6, the screen updates super quick and the application behaves as desirable. However, in Java 7 and 8, the application does not display anything. If I increase the delay between repaints, (to about 300 milliseconds) I am able to see the string flicker. However, if I wanted to develop a game in Java 8, the flickering and jittery motion of a character, for example, would be very undesirable.

Why do the different Java versions behave differently in this manner? Is there a way I am able to replicate the smooth repaint (by Java 6) in Java 8 using a similar setup? (as listed below) If there is, how? If not, how would one achieve a smooth, minimal flickering display? (I would prefer this repaint be constantly repainting, but it is not as necessary as the flow of the display)

Thanks for your help in advance,
 ~Rane

Java 6 Project Code:

```
public class App {

static AppDisplay display = new AppDisplay();

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    display.setup();

    Thread graphics = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        while(true) {
          display.repaint();
          try {
            Thread.sleep(17); // This is the delay I am talking about above
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    };
    graphics.start();


  }
}

public class AppDisplay() extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  int count = 0;

  public void setup() {
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setTitle("Application");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Count: " + count);
    count ++;
  }
}
```

Java 8 Code:

```
public class App {

static AppDisplay display = new AppDisplay();

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    display.setup();

    Thread graphics = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
        while(true) {
          display.repaint();
          try {
            Thread.sleep(17); // Delay
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
    };
    graphics.start();


  }
}

public class AppDisplay() extends JFrame {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  int count = 0;

  public void setup() {
    this.setSize(600, 600);
    this.setTitle("Application");
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setVisible(true);
  }

  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    g.drawString("Count: " + count);
    count ++;
  }
}
```

Comment: How can that code compile? Your class does not extend a Swing component, so there is no `super.paint(...)`. So shouldn't you extend JPanel or JComponent and then override `paintComponent(...)`? These details may seem small, but they matter quite a bit.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am so sorry. I forgot to include that in the code exmaples. I have added that. It IS in my code, I just forgot to include it here. Updated it now.

Comment: This code won't compile or run. You should post your actual code. But I suspect AppDisplay actually extends JFrame, and should not be overriding paint(), but rather paintComponent(). You were doing it wrong in Java 6 but you got away with it. Apparently newer versions are less forgiving.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Right :D. I saw his `while` loop but not the two lines above. Strange.

Comment: The likely cause is a misuse of the api which has been highlighted with the updates between Java 6 and Java 8. I've using much of the same paint code between these versions without issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Never draw directly in a JFrame ever.
- Always draw in a JComponent such as a JPanel or JComponent.
- And draw in its `paintComponent(Graphics g)` override, not in a `paint(Graphics g)` override to get the benefit of automatic double buffering.
- Please don't post sloppy code. If your class extends another class, show it. Details matter.

---

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class MyApp extends JPanel {

   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = 400;
   private static final int DELAY = 17;
   private int count = 0;

   public MyApp() {
      new Timer(DELAY, new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            count++;
            repaint();
         }
      }).start();
   }

   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawString("Count = " + count, 20, 20);
   }

   private static void createAndShowGUI() {
      MyApp paintEg = new MyApp();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyApp");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(paintEg);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: "If your class extends another class, show it." I added the extend part of the AppDisplay class. It extends JFrame. I apologize for forgetting this, but I have since then fixed the issue. Thank you for the other advice about paintComponent().

Comment: @Rane: your code also never makes the JFrame visible, making it hard to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfElese Sorry. Sorry for not proofreading my code more. I tried replicating my problem as much as possible without making it sloppy. However, I didn't get everything from my classes. I apologize to you, and to everyone who has tried to help me. I will take better efforts to ensure this doesn't happen again.

Comment: Just tried it. It worked. Thanks for being patient with me. Take care.  ~Rane

Comment: @Rane: glad you've got it working, and you're welcome!